# How to get a control reference from .ascx on a .aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a wizard setup like so:

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" DisplaySideBar="false" onnextbuttonclick="OnNextButtonClick">
       <WizardSteps>
           <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Step 1">
            <div class="content">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </div>
           </asp:WizardStep>
           <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" Title="Step 2">
               <div class="content">
                   <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
               </div>
           </asp:WizardStep> ...more
```

and then on the prerender of that page I add the controls like so:

```
protected void Wizard1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(LoadControl("Control1.ascx"));
    PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(LoadControl("Control2.ascx"));
    PlaceHolder3.Controls.Add(LoadControl("Control3.ascx"));
    ...more controls added
 }
```

and on the .ascx control I have a ajaxToolkit:TabContainer that I want to access like this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">  
            <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" HeaderText="PRV 1" runat="server">
```

So what I want to do is stop the wizard from going to the next step and move the ajaxtoolkit:Tabcontainer to the next tab.  I am accessing the nextbutton like so:

```
protected void OnNextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
     if(Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex == 2)
     {
          e.Cancel = true;
          //get ajaxToolKit:tabcontrol here
     }
}
```

Any ideas on how to access the TabControl in the OnNextButtonClick function? This is a asp.net webapplication.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but I'd say the wizard control should abstract this. If you want your wizard to 'do' something, it's better to tell it what you want it to do, rather than poking around its insides :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Page.GetControl("TabContainer1") or use a recursive method if you don't know the depth from your Page (useful with .ascx).

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control container, string name)
{
    if ((container.ID != null) && (container.ID.Equals(name)))
        return container;

    foreach (Control ctrl in container.Controls)
    {
        Control foundCtrl = FindControlRecursive(ctrl, name);
        if (foundCtrl != null)
            return foundCtrl;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Use it FindControlRecursive(Page, "TabContainer1")

Comment: The recursive method is not returning anything, it seems to cycle through the controls that are holding the TabContainer, any suggestions?

Comment: The recursive method works well. I'm using it to catch control in Page from ascx. But I see that you add control in PlaceHolder in PreRender step. Move it in Page_Init or the PlaceHolder would be empty when you fire OnNextButtonClick

Comment: yep that did it, thanks.  This is very useful for what i am doing.